# How to create a customer and add a credit card using stripe / angular / node

Tags: node.js, angular, stripe-payments

I been trying to figure out how to create a user and store his credit card info in stripe for like a day and I cant get it to work.

I can see the following docs:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_xxx');

const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs at https://www.stripe.com/docs/api)',
});
```

I understand the secret key aspect of the code.

I dont understand how to create the user object, though. where do I add the user name and info and email and stuff?

is there an example I can see using angular?
maybe the example can be for creating and storing the following information:
first name: juan
last name: cheese
email: jcasas@gmail.com

creditcard: 424242424242
csv: 231
creditcard name: juan cheese
exp: 02/02/25

i literally bough a course on udemy for this but that does not work either :(

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to save payment details, *without* an initial payment then you should follow [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web) from the Stripe documentation.

The process [creates a Customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#create-customer), and uses [Setup Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents) to correctly setup and save the payment details to that customer. Stripe.js and the [Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element) are used to safely collect payment details in a PCI compliant manner and handle any requested [3DS/authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication).